# Python Arduino - Comunicação Serial

Tags: arduino

Como faço a comunicação serial do Python com o arduino ? Já fiz a utilização da biblioteca pyserial, porém não consegui fazer a comunicação

Comment: Pode colocar o código na pergunta? A PySerial funciona bem com o Arduino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui está uma classe que criei para comunicar via Python. Com o código em Python é só usar as bibliotecas de comunicação serial do Arduino para receber e enviar os dados.

Na classe você tem o método para enviar uma lista de dados e para receber uma lista de dados. Agora é só definir seu protocolo de comunicação como: tamanho do buffer, cabeçalho, checksum, de acordo com sua necessidade!

```
import serial

class Comunicacao():

    def SerialInit(self, NomePorta, Velocidade, TimeRX, TimeTX):

        try:
            self.PortaCom = serial.Serial(NomePorta, Velocidade, 8, serial.PARITY_NONE, serial.STOPBITS_ONE, TimeRX,
                                          False, False, False, TimeTX)
            self.PortaCom.reset_input_buffer()
            self.PortaCom.reset_output_buffer()

        except Exception:
            print("Erro na porta " + NomePorta + "!")



    def WriteSerial(self, DadosTx):

        try:
            self.PortaCom.flushOutput()
            TamPac = DadosTx[3]
            for i in range(TamPac):
                DadoTxByte = bytes((DadosTx[i],))

                self.PortaCom.write(DadoTxByte)
                print(DadoTxByte)

        except Exception:
            print("Erro Escrita")

    def Leitura_Serial(self, DadosRx):

        LeituraSerial = [0] * 200

        for i in range(200):

            if (self.PortaCom.in_waiting > 0):
                LeituraSerial[i] = self.PortaCom.read()
                LeituraSerial[i] = self.ByteToInt(LeituraSerial[i])
                print(LeituraSerial[i])

            else:
                break

DadosTx = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
DadosRx = [0] * 100
PortaCom = Comunicacao()
PortaCom.SerialInit("/dev/ttyUSB0", 115200, 1, 1)
PortaCom.WriteSerial(DadosRx)
```

Comment: deu certo, muito obrigado !!!